# Image-recognition with opencv on Android app

Tags: android, opencv, image-recognition, image-comparison

I'm trying to do an android app. The idea is to make a picture of a road sign, the app compares that picture with a database that contains all the road sign and, if it is matched, it gives me information about that sign.

I kwon that OpenCV is great for my purpose, I installed all is needed to use it but i haven't found anything that explain me how I can use it to my goal.

Plesae, help me...